# Using applyBindingAccessorsToNode in custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm making a binding that simplifies adding a CSS class depending on a boolean value. I wanted to use `applyBindingAccessorsToNode` because it seems more clean than calling `.init` and `.update` of the native `css` binding in the new binding.

My issue is how to use `valueAccessor` because the binding seems to get parsed incorrectly depending of whether the provided value is an observable, an object or an evaluated observable.

The binding is this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ignoreValidation = {
    init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, { css: { ignoreValidation: valueAccessor() } }, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

This results in an error (the `[object Object]` is obviously unintended)

```
Message: Unable to process binding "ignoreValidation: function (){return showLookup }"
Message: Unable to process binding "css: [object Object]"
Message: d is not a function
```

TL;DR; I want to add a binding to an element programmatically without using both `update` and `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ko.applyBindingsToNode` works as expected:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ignoreValidation = {
  init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(
        element, 
        { css: { ignoreValidation: valueAccessor() }}, 
        bindingContext);
  }
}
```

An working example can be found in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67wsu5gd/1/).